# Browser keep a confusing cached version of angular app on root index.html hosted with azure app service

Tags: angular, azure, iis, web-config, angular-i18n

We currently have 2 versions of our Angular application on Azure/App services to support internalization.

There are hosted in the same place but on different folders **/en** and **/fr**.
Our folders tree looks like this

```
-> 
wwwroot/index.html
wwwroot/web.config
wwwroot/en/index.html
wwwroot/en/..
wwwroot/fr/index.html
wwwroot/fr/..
```

We do have a web.config rewrite rules which works perfectly. See below :

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Angular Routes fr" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="fr/.*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="fr/" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Angular Routes en" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="en/.*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="en/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is the twist; we do provide a root index.html in case the user navigate to `www.app.com/*` instead of `www.app.com/en`.
In this case the root index.html is triggered and we run some js script to redirect using "window.location.href" the user depending on the local storage language.

For some reason, when we are querying the url from the root `www.app.com`
the browser link and cached a first version to this url.

If we are querying the url with a resource like this `www.app.com/en/*`
the browser link ANOTHER version to this path despite the same domain.

The problem is that each time we deploy a new version only the path with any resources is being updated ex: `www.app.com/en/*` or `www.app.com/fr/*` but the root url `www.app.com` stay attached with an old version and never update.

If the user use the root url it will be redirected to an old version of the app only available in memory or disk.

Note that `www.app.com/en/*` or `www.app.com/fr/*` is working perfectly

At this point i don't know if the problem is our rewrite rules or our js script redirection.

Here is the angular build script for /en -> `ng build --output-path=dist/en --prod --base-href /en/ --i18n-locale en-CA --i18n-format=xlf`

Here is our root index.html code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <script>
        var edRedirectManager = (function () {
            var _this = {};

            _this.storageLocaleKey = "EDLocale";

            _this.locale = "";
            _this.init = function(){
                _this.locale = (_this.getUserLanguage());
            } 

            _this.redirect = function () {
                var currentUrl = new URL(window.location.href);

                var lgPrefix = _this.getUrlPrefixByLanguage();
                currentUrl.pathname = _this.insert(currentUrl.pathname,lgPrefix,0);

                window.location.href = currentUrl.href;
            }

            _this.getUserLanguage = function () {

                try {
                    _this.locale = localStorage.getItem(storageLocaleKey);
                } catch (error) {}

                if (!this.locale) {

                    if (navigator.language.toUpperCase().indexOf("FR") !== -1)
                        this.locale = "fr-CA";
                    else
                        this.locale = "en-CA";

                    localStorage.setItem(this.storageLocaleKey, this.locale);

                }

                return _this.locale;
            }

            _this.getUrlPrefixByLanguage = function(){
                var lgPrefix = "/fr";

                if(this.locale.indexOf('en') !== -1){
                    lgPrefix = "/en";
                }

                return lgPrefix;
            }

            _this.insert = function (main_string, ins_string, pos) {
                if (typeof (pos) == "undefined") {
                    pos = 0;
                }
                if (typeof (ins_string) == "undefined") {
                    ins_string = '';
                }
                return main_string.slice(0, pos) + ins_string + main_string.slice(pos);
            }


            return _this;
        })();
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <script>
        // self executing function here
        edRedirectManager.init();
        edRedirectManager.redirect();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: could you please attach exact requests and responses for index.html and /en or /fr are done when you navigate to index? it can easily be done with the help of "Preserve log" checkbox in chrome devtools network tab

Comment: by default "disable cache" checkbox is checked in network tab. that may be a reason it workd last time

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but without the internationalization stuff.  The browser loads from the cache when making a request for the root (response code 200?), but on any other path returns either 200 (gets new version) or 304 unmodified (cached version is correct).  I have a feeling this might be an Azure problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the *"/en/index.html"* and/or *"/fr/index.html"* page was cached when triggered from root "/" which cause old app main.js to load

The redirection worked just fined...

I added theses setting tag `<location>` in the web.config with *no-cache* value and now this problem is gone!

```
<configuration>
   <location path="en/index.html">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
    </location>
   <location path="fr/index.html">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
<location path="index.html">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
<system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Angular Routes fr" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="fr/.*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="fr/index.html" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Angular Routes en" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="en/.*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="en/index.html" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Angular Routes default" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```